# Using string Enums to extend keyof

Tags: typescript

I'm having a little trouble understanding how string enums behave when using them to index types.  It seems like sometimes TS recognizes that a string enum's value is an extension of `keyof` some type, and other times it doesn't.  To illustrate:

```
enum Key {
    FOO = "foo",
}

type MyObj = {
    foo: string
}
```

So, an enum of the properties of a type (i.e., you can index into `obj:MyObj` using `obj[Key.FOO]`).

Now I want to define another type that will lookup a value in the MyObj type to determine if it is a keyof that type and, if so, use the type of that key's value:

```
type FunctionReturn<T extends Record<string, any>,U extends keyof T> = {
    returnValue: U extends keyof T ? T[U]: never 
}
```

If I use that type as follows, though, I get an error.

```
function myFunction(value: MyObj[Key.FOO]):FunctionReturn<MyObj, Key.FOO>{
    return {returnValue: "a string"}
}
```

Namely, TS does not find the `U extends key of T` (where U is an enum member) to be satisfied in typing returnValue *even though* it accepted it as meeting the constraint of the FunctionReturn type.

The error goes away completely if I pass the actual string literal as the parameter.

```
function myOtherFunction(value: MyObj[Key.FOO]):FunctionReturn<MyObj, "foo">{
    return {returnValue: "a string"}
```

Why is that?  It seems to me if TS excepted `Key.FOO` as a valid extension of `keyof MyOb` in the generic constraint, it should also meet the conditional.  What am I missing?

Here's [the playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeUDeAoK6oDEDy2oF4oAiAMwHsyiAaFAXxRQBd4AHYKAWXmwCMArAsjQZyZAFxQAzowBOASxABzOg2ZssYEAGNGcsiABKwRmBkgAPABUowAB6NQAE0lQjWsjMfnp8pVSgAhiDwAHxUAKo29k4uANYIZCRQliGCqBhQMsamIABqAQA2YMASkXYOIM5Q8fCJyVAA-MkA2uEAuhIgwABuwDJQKigkmjp6IFAQ8JgjuvoAFN2FxRJcvHzNcPAAdDjYbQCUYtPas4bZZuar-P6bO7gh6RhZJmbIzzn5RSXEAVKyCooiPR6EMZmMJtxGAALPrHUbzRZfFbcfgbBB3PaHOGnIwvCxXPj%20UgUIgPYTod6vJCUvJLb5EX4%20AFAuhAA)

Much appreciated, as always.

Comment: This is a good question. @sam256 please take a look on this demo: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgaTgTxgbwFAyEwBiA8qTALwwBEAZiCDQDR4C+eeUmADnDAFlMpAEYArKrgJEGIAFwxoAJwCWYAObtO3PjAAqcaAB49kgIZhMzGAFVzlgHySMmAHRkKcAB5QEAEwgYAGssEDpBYXEYAH4I0TEAbRd3cgBdGAUwOAA3OCVtXn5iFSVoSQNjIXjrZI8nAHp6mCzc-J1+AGU4UDA-ZywUzx9-QJDMMLio2KglRH4FOjMAGwh+RpgZuc4gA  .  First and Second types return different results, even if they are almost equals

Comment: Yeah, enums have some bizarre assignability rules I don't understand.  I'm having flashbacks to [microsoft/TypeScript#21998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21998).  My guess is that any answer will involve some shrugging and pointing to enums being unsound.  Personally I stay away from enums unless I treat them as completely *opaque*, meaning the only TS code that knows their value is the `enum` statement itself.  For example, if you define `type MyObj = { [Key.FOO]: string }` and never use the `"foo"` literal (pretend you don't know it) you should be okay.

Comment: If you think that is acceptable as an answer I'll write it up; otherwise ‍♂️ good luck!

Comment: String enums aren't assignable to the corresponding string literal types. [This is intentional.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17690#issuecomment-321319291)

Comment: @cherryblossom, appreciate the pointers on string enums, but see the proposed answer using a third parameter.  i'm totally confused as to why _that_ works.  it makes me think that this is more than just a string-enums-are-weird issue, but (also) something i don't fully get about conditionals.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for the proposed workaround.  i've also found that using `const Key = {FOO: "foo"} as const` works as a pseudo-enum.  I was hoping to understand why the difference in behavior, now with the added complication of why the V=T[U] workaround in the proposed answer works...  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such trick:

```
enum Key {
    FOO = "foo",
}

type MyObj = {
    foo: string
}

/*
  I've added V generic parameter to tell TS to use U as keyof T, not as something else. 
  Now it works as expected.
*/
type FunctionReturn<T extends Record<string, any>,U extends keyof T, V = T[U]> = {
    returnValue: U extends keyof T ? V: never 
}

function myFunction(value: MyObj[Key.FOO]):FunctionReturn<MyObj, Key.FOO>{
    return {returnValue: "a string"}
}

function myOtherFunction(value: MyObj[Key.FOO]):FunctionReturn<MyObj, "foo">{
    return {returnValue: "a string"}
}
```

Some explanation:

Let's take it from the beginning. The function expects `U extends keyof T` as the second type variable. It means you can pass anything that's assignable to `keyof T` and also it means that `U` within function execution can be any type that's assignable to `keyof T`. When you pass `Key.FOO` as `U`, TS checks assignability to `keyof T` and it will be passed. Then, TS infers type of `U` as `Key` (that's important thing). Then, because of `U extends keyof T` will be resolved to true, TS will resolve `T[U]` to `T[Key]`. Then, to resolve `T[key]` TS will make intersection with constraint `keyof T`, like this `T[Key & keyof T]`, which in turn resolves to `T[never]`. The most interesting thing is that such intersection `Key.FOO & "foo"` will be resolved to `never`. Why to `never`? Well, probably because of strict rule, like any intersection enum with some other type except enum itself in TS will be resolved to `never`.

---

Why suggested approach works:

When you use `FunctionReturn` like this `FunctionReturn<MyObj, Key.FOO>`, TS first resolves generic parameters:

```
T = MyObj,
U = Key.FOO,
V = MyObj[Key.FOO] = string
```

Because there is no indexed access inside true branch, there is no need to resolve it somehow, TS just uses type string inside true branch.

Comment: This is really interesting.  Can you explain why it works?  It makes me thinking the problem is not just the peculiarities of string enums but also something to do with how conditionals work?

Comment: @sam256 I wrote some explanations.