# Why the type of `SomeObject[SomeEnum]` is never here

Tags: typescript

```
export enum NativeApiEndpoint {
  test = "test",
}
export interface NativeApiEndpointContentMap {
  test: string
}
type GetContentType<T extends NativeApiEndpoint> = T extends keyof NativeApiEndpointContentMap ? NativeApiEndpointContentMap[T] : undefined
type GetContentTypeTest<T extends NativeApiEndpoint> = T extends keyof NativeApiEndpointContentMap ? true : false
type a = GetContentType<NativeApiEndpoint.test>
// a is never
type b = GetContentTypeTest<NativeApiEndpoint.test>
// b is true
type c = NativeApiEndpointContentMap[NativeApiEndpoint.test]
// c is string
```

And here is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwHIEMYEsBuwAgmLgKKIAmkui8A3gFBxwzADO8AvHAERudeAGkYBfRo1CRYcWmygAzLAGNgmHAWKkK1CHIDCEOkhgBZLGDhMWAmAC44nKLQDmYiTACeYNQHFgMIbGdAAq3sAAPCEIIGxU7Op4hCTkVDR0AHxwPNGgcZQJANbAnhAKiZopOumBRnFmFnAA-BXJ2ml6dEH15mAA2iEAunAOyFTACrTAlIxePnD%20tcEwYT4hHDBRMfkJ2ElaqbpyWTnbSAVwxaXle5XtR111Jr3NrFDIag5KADbswB7hOBYbILALdEyrSK3NqHGoAOlsGUYAHpkUDZAlEMBCFAAfMAEYgxbg0LhdacCLQg7VTowBEbJGouCE3AJGDvf6zQHKEFUqodAxPOi9Pp8%207w2yDFFonmsxzs1xAA)

As we can see, b is true and c is string, why a is never

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64812755/8289918

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

In your case `NativeApiEndpointContentMap` can not be indexed by `NativeApiEndpoint` type, because there is no connection between them

### Theory

Enums are not simple strings as you would expect. **You can not index some type with enum values, if you don't explicitly define this behaviour**, even if string values are the same.

```
export enum NativeApiEndpoint {
  test = "test",
  some = 'some',
  other = 'other'
}

// false
type check = NativeApiEndpoint extends 'test' ? true : false;

// also false
type check2 = 'test' extends NativeApiEndpoint ? true : false;

// true
type check3 = NativeApiEndpoint.test extends NativeApiEndpoint ? true : false;

// true
type check4 = NativeApiEndpoint.test extends 'test' ? true : false;

// false
type check5 = 'test' extends NativeApiEndpoint.test ? true : false;

type CheckContentType<T extends NativeApiEndpoint> = T extends keyof NativeApiEndpointContentMap
  ? T extends never
    ? 'T is never'
    : 'Works'
  : undefined

// en is of type NativeApiEndpoint, not of type 'test' as you would expect
type en = NativeApiEndpoint.TEST
// checkType is of type `T is never`
type checkType = CheckContentType<en>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwHIEMYEsBuwAgmLgKKIAmkui8A3gFBxwzADO8AvHAERudeAGmZx2EVMDg8A5OMkyRLCDAAWwKNLgyV6qDMYBfRowD0puADMsAG3bBGMAJ5gpAY3VuA1lux5CJORUNHQIIGxU7NoCMDJwAPysUMhSAFxWtvYA3CbmcJkQGXYOzq5wHsDeAExaMjFxoBGUUX4ExKQU1BC08IkwyWlF2bkW-SmOLu6eXgDMvjhtgZ0hMAB0MWFNLQsBHcHdoX0DcOnWxTlmowMTZRXeACzz-u1BXT3rHPCNSM3Rn3FHFInIbAC55M72G5TSpeACstXqmx+22eS327w2gMGENBQA)

#### Solution 1 - explicitly index your interface with enum

```
export enum NativeApiEndpoint {
  test = "test",
  some = 'some',
  other = 'other'
}

export interface NativeApiEndpointContentMap {
  [NativeApiEndpoint.test]: string;
  [NativeApiEndpoint.some]: number;
}

type GetContentType<T extends NativeApiEndpoint> = T extends keyof NativeApiEndpointContentMap ? NativeApiEndpointContentMap[T] : undefined

// some is number
type some = GetContentType<NativeApiEndpoint.some>
// which equals
type somee1 = NativeApiEndpointContentMap[NativeApiEndpoint.some]

// test is string
type test = GetContentType<NativeApiEndpoint.test>
// which equals
type test1 = NativeApiEndpointContentMap[NativeApiEndpoint.test]

// other is undefined, because it's key is not defined on `NativeApiEndpointContentMap`
type other = GetContentType<NativeApiEndpoint.other>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwHIEMYEsBuwAgmLgKKIAmkui8A3gFBxwzADO8AvHAERudeAGmZx2EVMDg8A5OMkyRLCDAAWwKNLgyV6qDMYBfRo1CRYcWmygAzLAGMp2PIRLkqNOgGEIdJDABZLDA4JhYAbWcCYlIKaggrADoBGABdAC4xGChaAHMAblFInGi3OM8YRPlgDLgUVAAjDULjRhgATzApAHFgGB8-OgAVTuAAHiGEEDYqdkwS11iPBLoAPi1J0BnKOYBrYHaIG3mXGPd4qwGZwOC4AH4T0qWL719roLBwodS4TOQqYA2WjASgmAD0YLEEikuDm9SaUDaoyhki0vX6b38Iy6Yyii3OFSq0NWjAhcAA7qpcPZVAgAI7ILAAG3YSK6KOAwAAjFo8WdyisMYMbp8+WVlklqqlwZCUpY5pwcohcmypHKeOirljRriFvyJXRkhwYCSyZTqbTgAzmayOuyUjyeGLnhUtXQPsVTuKXpUUtLSZDdBp5XB-pRAcDKEI4E17FhkOwYTA5HB9u0Q4gVHBw0DECC4L44AADZ0EwVukVF1UFtTBjV9CvY8algVJINQVZAA)

#### Solution 2 - flip GetContentType `extends` checks

```
export enum NativeApiEndpoint {
  test = "test",
  some = 'some',
  other = 'other'
}

export interface NativeApiEndpointContentMap {
  test: string;
  some: number;
  problem: 'problem';
}

type GetContentType<T extends keyof NativeApiEndpointContentMap> = T extends NativeApiEndpoint
  ? NativeApiEndpointContentMap[T]
  : undefined

// some is number
type some = GetContentType<NativeApiEndpoint.some>
// which equals, but in this case GetContentType also adds constraint for passed parameter to be of `NativeApiEndpoint` type
type some1 = NativeApiEndpointContentMap[NativeApiEndpoint.some]

// could work, but 'problem' is not of type NativeApiEndpoint, so following type is undefined
type porblem = GetContentType<'problem'>

// errors, beacause `NativeApiEndpointContentMap` can not be indexed with 'other'
type other = GetContentType<NativeApiEndpoint.other>
type other1 = NativeApiEndpointContentMap[NativeApiEndpoint.other]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAhAOwK4FsEDkCGcCWAbiAIIT4CiyAJtPsogN7AIJwgDOiAvAgETsufADQsEHKOhAJeAcglTZo1lDgALEDBkJZqjTFnAAvsFCRYieuxgAzHAGNpuAsTKUadBgGEoDFHABZHAgEZlZBOAAucTgYegBzAG4xBRBotHQAI01k1ggYKEyAGxB0aNl8wpL0WWSTYDgATwhpAHEQOB8-BgAVZpAAHh6kMHYaDgQAaxBGqBtsPCJScipaKCsuscDggD5tYfAx6gnnJbdVzzgxAH4Fl2X3NY3fLaCIAG0egF0xaNQaEA2eggaimAD0YPEkmk+AmGWyMAa-ShUm07U6L38fRaA1OrhWHnWDAAdKkdsAIQgAO5qfD2NRIACOqBwRQ4wgQmVQlmQbFpE3sOA4bQ6myxyNZEgQOGoxwQ9l8XBgOCsCBssAQECFwuompwyqk1jYUE50jmCAABniHhciXALWx+kiWiiQABGbTW86E57dbYfL0Ep4k1I-CmQhWoIq6qmwSYcrmICoFYqlWQIWEIZCqBDmpouwOPS4cqXqopFKBUhKOl2Z-7UQHA0H56TQGCpzC8dFi3r9AbJqpp8nhpAwAowdmmhw4VDCy2F22+17BB2C3nZxDZDMAsAg6n4dQ6PSaQwt3PqTRo0WY3s4hc+knHmDks9Pj28e-BjF+t7vT+XYkny+IA)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'm looking for! Sometimes TypeScript is so confusing for me.